# Isolate scope value not being passed to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using [angular-slider.js](https://github.com/prajwalkman/angular-slider) on a page that makes a server request when the value of the slider changes. I don't want this to happen until the user has let go of the mouse button, in other words onmouseup.

This is pretty easy to do in a directive using the '=' isloate scope and passing this to a scope variable.

However, the same thing in angular-slider doesn't behave as I would expect.

In the html I have added the attribute 'mousewatch', which is assigned the $scope variable 'mouseStatus'

```
$scope.mouseStatus = 0;

<slider floor="0" ceiling="10" ng-model-low="pMinBedsVal" ng-model-high="pMaxBedsVal" mousewatch="mouseStatus"></slider>
```

... and added this to the directive as an isolate scope:

```
  sliderDirective = function($timeout) {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {
        floor: '@',
        ceiling: '@',
        step: '@',
        precision: '@',
        ngModel: '=?',
        ngModelLow: '=?',
        ngModelHigh: '=?',
        translate: '&',
        mousewatch: "="
      },
```

...finally I have added the values of mousewatch to the onEnd and onStart events in the slider directive:

```
            onEnd = function() {
              pointer.removeClass('active');
              scope.mousewatch = 0;
              console.log("mouseup");
              ngDocument.unbind(events.move);
              return ngDocument.unbind(events.end);
            };

            onStart = function(event) {
              pointer.addClass('active');
              scope.mousewatch = 1;
              console.log("mousedown");
              dimensions();
              event.stopPropagation();
              event.preventDefault();
              ngDocument.bind(events.move, onMove);
              return ngDocument.bind(events.end, onEnd);
            };
```

The problem is that the value set for scope.mousewatch in the directive is not passed to $scope.mouseStatus in the controller.

Answer (score 2):

So I figured out a way to approach this that works. Instead of using the '=' isolate scope, I use the '&' so that I can pass a value to a function in the controller.

```
mousewatch: '&'
```

Then, in the onStart and onEnd events, I pass the value I want into mousewatch() using the {key:value} syntax.

```
            onEnd = function() {
              pointer.removeClass('active');
              scope.mousewatch({status:0});
              ngDocument.unbind(events.move);
              return ngDocument.unbind(events.end);
            };

            onStart = function(event) {
              pointer.addClass('active');
              scope.mousewatch({status:1});
              dimensions();
              event.stopPropagation();
              event.preventDefault();
              ngDocument.bind(events.move, onMove);
              return ngDocument.bind(events.end, onEnd);
            };
```

The html to call the directive then needs the status variable in the function that is to be called:

```
<slider floor="0" ceiling="10" ng-model-low="pMinBedsVal" ng-model-high="pMaxBedsVal" mousewatch="callMouse(status)"></slider>
```

And finally, there's the function in the controller itself:

```
$scope.callMouse = function (status){
    console.log("mouseStatus...." + status);
};
```

That's it. Now it is possible to make my calls to the backend once the mouse button is released.